# Wait for axios API call in vuex to finish before continuing vue-router guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, vuex, vue-router

I have a django-rest-axios-vuejs application stack for which I'm trying to do something in the `vue-router`.

In the `vue-router` `beforeEach` guard, I'm verifying permissions and it is done by checking something in an object called `me` in vuex store. Everything works well except when I refresh the page.

Indeed refreshing the page also clears vuex store and my `beforeEach` tries to check the `me` object from the store which is empty.

Therefore I'd like to fetch this `me` object from the API if it isn't in the store.
The problem is that it takes "some time" and the `hasPermission()` method executes before the API call is finished.

So I tried to put a `await` keyword before my API call but it doesn't work.

> My `beforeEach` guard :

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const isLoggedIn = getIsLoggedIn()
  handleLoggedInStatus(isLoggedIn)
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (to.meta.permission) {
        if (!store.state.me) await store.dispatch('FETCH_ME')
        hasPermission(to.meta.permission) ? next() : next({ name: 'HomePage' })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next({ name: 'LoginForm' })
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

> My action from the store :

```js
actions: {
    FETCH_ME: (state) => {
      http
        .get('base/users/me/')
        .then(response => {
          state.me = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
  }
```

The only way I've found to make it wait is to do the following :

```js
function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  const isLoggedIn = getIsLoggedIn()
  handleLoggedInStatus(isLoggedIn)
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      if (to.meta.permission) {
        if (!store.state.me) {
          store.dispatch('FETCH_ME')
          await sleep(2000)
        }
        hasPermission(to.meta.permission) ? next() : next({ name: 'HomePage' })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      next({ name: 'LoginForm' })
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

To make it wait a "random" (2 seconds) amount of time with a little `sleep()` method.

I'm kinda new to the usage of `async` `await` so.. What am I missing to make `await store.dispatch('FETCH_ME')` work ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found this [LINK](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#composing-actions) which I didn't see before...

This allowed me to rewrite my `FETCH_ME` action like this :

```js
FETCH_ME ({ commit }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http
     .get('base/users/me/')
     .then(response => {
       commit('SET_ME', response.data)
       resolve()
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(error)
       reject(error)
     })
   })
}
```

where `SET_ME` is a mutation I already had :

```js
SET_ME: (state, user) => {
  state.me = user
},
```

Which is finally working for my case, where doing this in the `router.beforeEach` guard :

`if (!store.state.me) await store.dispatch('FETCH_ME')` effectively waits for the `dispatch` action to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I have a pet project with similar logic. I am not using meta

```
async beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
   await store.dispatch('getUser')
   if (store.getters.user) return next()
    next('/login')
}
```

The logic is the following. If the user is logged in, there is a cookie in the browser and it's being sent with the store.dispatch. And if the token is valid, backend returns the user, ie if the getter returns the user, the user is logged in. I think your logic should be the same